# Help troubleshooting my bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, blueman

I think Bluetooth on this machine works, at least the hardware does. I've seen it function briefly once so that implies it might function longer than just a few seconds.

I had this problem but was able to make it go away:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/690863/sound-fluctuates-wildly-back-and-forth-as-sound-device-rapidly-appears-and-disap

I have this hardware:

```
sudo bluez-test-adapter list
 [ /org/bluez/599/hci0 ]
    Name = warmachine-0
    Powered = 1
    Devices = dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)
    DiscoverableTimeout = 0
    PairableTimeout = 0
    Discoverable = 1
    Address = 24:0A:64:03:BF:94
    Discovering = 0
    Pairable = 1
    Class = 0x000000
    UUIDs = dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'00001001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String(u'0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'), variant_level=1)
```

From DMesg on startup:

```
[    9.342995] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    9.343006] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    9.343007] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.343013] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.343015] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.343017] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.344379] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    9.350125] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.350134] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.350139] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    9.351624] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    9.354582] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (626) terminated with status 1
[    9.354598] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[    9.354615] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000002, interface fatal error
[    9.354628] ata2.00: failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
[    9.354643] ata2.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 7 pio 512 in
[    9.354643]          res 50/00:03:00:24:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[    9.354669] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[    9.354680] ata2: hard resetting link
[    9.356030] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.356032] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.356037] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Also

```
sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 24:0A:64:03:BF:94 Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout
```

...and lastly.

```
lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2net; uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; rfkill list all; hciconfig -a
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:17cf ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1e7d:3264 ROCCAT 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1e7d:2d51 ROCCAT Kone+ Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:0994 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Orbit/Sphere AF
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
grep: 2net: invalid context length argument
Linux warmachine 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    0.189642] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    9.342995] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    9.343007] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.343013] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.343015] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.343017] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.350125] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.350134] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.350139] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    9.356030] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.356032] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.356037] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 24:0A:64:03:BF:94  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:934 acl:0 sco:0 events:88 errors:0
    TX bytes:1739 acl:0 sco:0 commands:80 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'warmachine-0'
    Class: 0x6c0100
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

I have several Bluetooth devices here, my phone and a headset but they do not scan at all. ...and yet I've seen this machine register bluetooth devices, they just don't stay that way and afterwards you can't scan anything at all.

```
dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.199286] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    9.554021] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    9.554038] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.554045] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.554047] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.554051] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.556384] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.556389] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.556392] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    9.556650] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.556652] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.556655] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Please edit to add results from `lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2net; uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; rfkill list all; hciconfig -a`  Thanks

Comment: @Jeremy31 Done.

Comment: Can you update to a 3.16 kernel  and then do `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` as the source code for 3.13 would need patched for it to work

Comment: I've added the kernel PPA but what packages? My kernel is x86_64 but I don't see one of those in the list of kernels.  Should I go with amd_64?

Comment: I don't think you want the kernel PPA, do you have hybrid graphics that need proprietary drivers?  If you don't you can check out [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Desktop) to update to the 3.19 kernel

Comment: nVidia. It's actually my game machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a DKMS module that you can use with the 3.13 kernel, to install

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yfcg4e2mn1zcs0/fw-0b05-17cf.hcd
sudo cp fw-0b05-17cf.hcd /lib/firmware/fw-0b05_17cf.hcd
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/ol5r9dai967p6by/btusb-dkms_3.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i btusb-dkms_3.1_all.deb
```

Reboot and bluetooth should function correctly

Comment: Didn't work.  New devices show up only once and won't pair.

Comment: Run `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` once again

Comment: lorem ipsum Done.

Comment: See the info after EDIT in the answer

Comment: Bingo! Fix to remove erroneous information and I'll select as answer. :-):-):-)

Comment: answer edited :-)